# Make ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT override the file if the file already exists instead of appending (n) to it

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using the `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` intent when creating a file in my app.
To support scoped storage, I am trying to use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` to create a file, but in case the file is already present, Android's Storage Access Framework (SAF) by default appends (n) to the file and does not override the old file.

Is there any way to to find a way that file already exists or force override the file with a warning?

Comment: Very nice question. I imedeately started some testing. It looks as if you are without luck. But who knows..

Comment: Any solution found so far?

Answer (score -1):

In the FilePicker, when the user picks an existing file, the FilePicker will ask the user if the chosen file must be overridden.