# android: Skip ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT if it exists

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, android-permissions, intentservice

I would like to ask the user to create a folder at the root of his volume if it doesn't exist yet.
This has to be achieved through SAF and with ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT to get the rights to read/write on the sdcard.

I used to check if the directory exists by

1. asking access to the document tree with "ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE"
2. check with `if (!DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, workingDirUri).exists())`

But with Android 11 it is not possible anymore to do the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE on the root of the volume, and ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT doesn't permit to select a directory). If I try to bypass the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE and check if the directory exists with the method above, android 11 returns a "*Permission denied, you need to grant permissions to with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT*" or something like that, I don't remember the exact wording.

For now, my workaround is to use the `File` class to check if the directory exists, but this is not very elegant.

How would you do this by staying with SAF calls? Is there an option to tell ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT to skip if the document already exists?

BTW: there is a parent unanswered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62464770/15401262) asking for overriding, which is not exactly my issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On Android 11:

If you use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE you can let the user choose 'WorkingDir' (if it exists already) or let the user create and select it.

You are done then as the uri you obtain exists.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this case, is it possible to prefill the name of the directory ? I would have prefered it to be automatic (for example if it doesn't exist let the user create it, and if it does exist, just don't show anything). Ideally I would prefer not to ask anything if it does exist.